# How to get the value repetition count on array of objects for all entries on mongodb aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have the data structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4404906736bd2608e30b5e"),
    "assets": [ 
        {
            "name" : "xa",
            "id"   : 1
        },
        {
            "name" : "xs",
            "id"   : 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4404906736bd2608e30b5f"),
    "assets": [ 
        {
            "name" : "xa",
            "id"   : 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4404906736bd2608e30b5g"),
    "assets": [ 
        {
            "name" : "xa",
            "id"   : 4
        },
        {
            "name" : "xd",
            "id"   : 5
        },
        {
            "name" : "xs",
            "id"   : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to implement the MongoDB aggregation by which I got the Answer like this:

```
[
 {
  "assets": "xa",
  "count": 3
 },
 {
  "assets": "xs",
  "count": 2
 },
 {
  "assets": "xd",
  "count": 1
 },
]
```

I have to get this done by javascript but need to implement this on aggregation. My code for acheiveing with js is like this for set of array of object i.e

```
var arr = [
  { asset: "xa" },
  { asset: "xs" },
  { asset: "xa" },
  { asset: "xs" },
  { asset: "xa" },
  { asset: "xd" }
];

var userDict = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(el.asset)) {
    acc[el.asset] = { count: 0 };
  }
  acc[el.asset].count++;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.entries(userDict).map(([k, v]) => ({
  asset: k,
  count: v.count
}));
console.log(result);
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) `assets` before applying [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with count:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$assets"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$assets.name",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            asset: "$_id",
            count: 1
        }
    }
])
```